# data flow analysis reaching definition analysis meaning

Tags: data-flow-analysis

I'm trying to understand reaching definitions and I'm having hard problem wrapping it around my head with the following definition (taken from the the following [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=2f25cb60ce7c12d067c0fe3dafef7e9a7896ea3c) page 114):

- $B_i\;\text{be a basic block}$
- $ReachIn(B_i)\;\text{be the set of registers that reach the entrance to}\;B_i$
- $ReachOut(B_i)\;\text{be the set of registers that reach the exit from}\;B_i$
- $Kill(B_i)\;\text{be the set of registers killed in}\;B_i$
- $Def(B_i)\;\text{be the set of registers defined in}\;B_i$

Then

$$
\begin{align*}
& ReachIn(B_i) = \begin{cases}\bigcup \scriptsize p \in Pred(B_i)\normalsize \;ReachOut(p) && \scriptsize\text{If $B_i$ is not the header node} \\
\emptyset && \scriptsize\text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
& ReachOut(B_i) = Defs(B_i)\bigcup (ReachIn(B_i) - Kill(B_i))
\end{align*}
$$

Why part of the expression of $ReachOut(B_i)$ is set to be the $ReachIn(B_i) - Kill(B_i)$ if for every assignment say $a = b + c$ we **kill** the old definition of $a$ but we create a new **definition** for $a$ so what's the point of subtracting the the `Kill` set from the `ReachIn` set if we later add the `Def` set to it?

I wonder if the author meant the definitions to be for general data flow analysis where we want to computer the `ReachIn` and `ReachOut` sets for an arbitrary point in the program and not necessarily the entry and exit of a basic blocks where in my understanding every **kill** also **redefines** a variable/register, but even that what the author meant, why he chose to be specific about defining $B_i$ as a basic block, meaning the `ReachIn` and `ReachOut` definitions are coupled to the entry and the exit of the basic block.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all material originally written by others.  Please [edit] your post to provide proper attribution for the definition you are quoting.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing